# Using a custom query to get data

Tags: wordpress

I've been thinking of creating my own custom query to get data using `$wpdb`. But there are just some things I don't quite understand:

1. When the results come in, how will it know which template file to use to display those results?
2. What do I type in the link's `href` attribute which will activate the query?
3. Should there be many results, will pagination be enabled like a normal loop?
4. Do I put my query in a file (in #1) or in `functions.php`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create new custom loop, you can create new template for it. In this case pagination, loop work normally. You just place custom wp_query above loop. And in href you must write url of page which built on new custom template. For understanding all this process step by step i suggest you to read my article in wptuts. It is called "[Creating a Custom ‘The Posts I Commented On’ Loop](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-custom-the-posts-i-commented-on-loop/)" and it is the guide what you need.

Comment: I see where you're getting at. So I need to create the page manually first.